# RegEx to find all symbol 'y' between consonant letters

Tags: regex

I need to find all symbol 'y' between consonant letters:
For example in `'tyrypyr'` i need to find y at 2, 4 and 6 position.
In `'tyraypyr'` - in 2 and 7 and NOT in 5 because `a` in front of `y`.

I try `/[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ]y[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ]/gi` pattern. But it is not capture middle `y` in `'tyrypyr'` (find only `'tyr'` and `'pyr'`)

If add `*` in expression like `/[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ]*y[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ]/gi`, but incorrectly  match `y` after `a` in `tyraypyr`.

What is the right way to find symbol `y` between consonant letters. And, if it is possible just `y` (without consonant letters i.e. `y` instead `'tyr'` and `'pyr'`). Because I want find this `y` to replace it with another symbols.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? I guess JavaScript?

Comment: c# library in MS SQL, i guess

Comment: Why is there `/gi` then?

Comment: but i am testing regex at https://regex101.com/

Comment: g = global, don't return after first match, i = case insensitive match

Comment: Use something like `(?<![aeiou])y(?![aeiou])` then. This will match singular `y` characters, unlike the answers below.

Comment: In C#? .NET regex does not use regex delimiters.

Comment: @Phylogenesis : your regex is wrong. It matches `yby` twice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did find the lack of love for my answer surprising, but really it doesn't matter :) Un-accepting the accepted answer now wouldn't be very nice either. Thanks though !

Comment: @Aaron i'm sorry, but i can't accept two answer simultaneously. I try, but it uncheck another answer in this case

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  i'm sorry, but i can't accept two answer simultaneously. I try, but it uncheck another answer in this case

Comment: You'd better change the accepted answer today: if you do it any time tomorrow or later, it would be worse, the user would wake up with -15 points in his/her account.

Comment: @Andrey: To be fair, Aaron should get the accepted answer. We wrote it in parallel and basically had the same answer, but he was done 2 minutes before.

Comment: @Eric Duminil ok. I have changed accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
(?<=[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])y(?=[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/nihd4Y/2).

This works when your regex doesn't because the lookahead is a 0-width match which doesn't forward your match pointer, while your regex was consuming the next consonant.

Answer (score 1):

You need [positive Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/(?<=[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])y(?=[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])/gi
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/HgPOo5/1) it is

Your match was 3 characters long. `tyrypyr` is 7 characters long, so you could only find it twice at most.

Comment: I disagree, using negative lookaheads/lookbehinds will match `y` characters at the start and end of strings.

Comment: @Phylogenesis hu? no it won't. See this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nihd4Y/2)

Comment: Exactly. See the last line in the question. He *wants* it to match a singular `y` character if possible.

Comment: @Phylogenesis A singular `y` as in "not the three letters, just the y in the middle". I was confused too but the example makes it clear

Comment: I now realise where the confusion has come from. I read the last line as though he wanted to also match single `y` characters rather than wanting the match result to return just the single `y` character matched (and not its surrounding characters). I blame the imprecision of the English language.